# EF Core Code First - Clustered Index and Identity Column

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core 2.0 to create a table in which the primary key is a `GUID` and the clustered index is an auto-incrementing `INT` column.  But I'm getting this error:

> Cannot create more than one clustered index on table 'Tenants'. Drop the existing clustered index 'PK_Tenants' before creating another

This is the code for creating entity and Fluent API.

**Tenant.cs**

```
public class Tenant : EntityBase
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ClusteredId { get; set; }
    public new Guid TenantId { get; set; }

    public string TenantCode { get; set; }
}
```

**FluentAPI**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
        builder.Entity<Tenant>().HasIndex(c => c.TenantId).ForSqlServerIsClustered(false);
        builder.Entity<Tenant>().HasIndex(c => c.ClusteredId).HasName("ClusteredId").ForSqlServerIsClustered(true);

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
}
```

Please suggest, how to remove this error and create primary key for `GUID` and clustered index for auto-incrementing `INT` column.

Thanks.

Comment: `modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>().HasAlternateKey(t => t.TenantId);                //Auto increment
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>().HasKey(t => t.ClusteredId);` will work for you

Answer (score 4):

The PK index is not maintained explicitly. In EF Core it can be configured via `KeyBuilder` fluent API (note the `HasKey` in place of `HasIndex`):

```
    builder.Entity<Tenant>().HasKey(c => c.TenantId).ForSqlServerIsClustered(false);
    builder.Entity<Tenant>().HasIndex(c => c.ClusteredId).HasName("ClusteredId").ForSqlServerIsClustered(true);
```